# onclick no es una funcion ¿como lo corrigo?

Tags: javascript

lo que busco realizar es un menu en la parte izquierda de la pagina web para visualizar diferentes tipos de categorias asi que decidi crear una lista de etiquetas a donde le coloque el valor de que tipo de categoria es y cuando vaya hacer click
aplicar un event.preventDefault() y obtener el valor de ese etiqueta y buscar y actualizar
una parte de la pagina web para consultar los productos.
pero me sale un error en la consola que es ***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: itemCategoria.onclick is not a function*** alguna sugerencia de como corregir el error o como lo harian ustedes gracias

```
   function consultaFirebase() {
    firebaseConfig.ref('categoria').once('value').then(datos => {
        datos.forEach(element => {
            tarjetaCategoria(element)
        });
    })
}


function tarjetaCategoria(params) {
    var itemCategoria = document.createElement('a');
    itemCategoria.innerHTML=`${params.val().tipoCategoria}`;
    itemCategoria.href = params.val().tipoCategoria;
    itemCategoria.onclick('click', () => {
        console.log('ok');
    })
    producto.appendChild(itemCategoria)    
}
```

Comment: Estás confundiendo 2 cosas.

Comment: @Mateo ¿como seria?

Comment: Te lo acabo de explicar en una respuesta. Estabas mezclando las dos formas de agregar el evento. onclick es una propiedad, por eso te da el error cuando intentas llamarlo con `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los eventos se pueden declarar de dos formas:

- Mediante el atributo `onclick` en HTML, que es a lo que la propiedad (no es una función) `.onclick` hace referencia en Javascript. De esta manera se puede asignar solo un handler.

  ```
  itemCategoria.onclick = function () {
      console.log('realizar accion');
  }
  ```
- Mediante la función `addEventListener()`. El primer parámetro es el evento y el segundo la función a ejecutar (también puede ser una función flecha). Con este método puedes agregar todos los handlers que necesites.

  ```
  listener1 = itemCategoria.addEventListener('click', () => {
     ​console.log('realizar accion');
  })
  ```

Para eliminarlo debes guardar el objeto que devuelve la función `addEventListener()` y pasárselo de una manera similar a `removeEventListener()`:

```
  itemCategoria.removeEventListener('click', listener1)
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, quizá solo falta agregar porqué es mejor usar [.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#why_use_addeventlistener.3f)

Comment: Más allá de que uno admite múltiples handlers y el otro no, no sé que otros puntos positivos tenga.

Comment: Según la documentación: Da un control más detallado de la fase en la que el listener se activa (capturing vs. bubbling) y Funciona en cualquier elemento del DOM, no únicamente con elementos de HTML.